# Data to use for cluster analysis

Tags: clustering

I have a data frame of employees hours at work. The variables are time coming to work, time going home (finishing work), and time worked for the day, which is not the difference of going home and starting work as the lunch time could vary and there could be other breaks. The data frame also has personal numbers of each employee, their grades and dates (weekdays).

I want to see if certain weekdays are more alike with others in terms of the three variables measuring the time at work. I also would like to see if certain grades are more alike with other grades in terms of the same variables. I am new to cluster analysis, but my understanding is that to do this I do not use the initial data set, but rather compute for example in the case of grades the means for each grade and than use the means (for coming to work, going home and time worked) to create the clusters. Is that right? If it has any importance I am going to use R. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use cluster analysis at all. It will do "something" (attempt to discover some structure in the data), but not what *your* hypothesis is.

Instead, formulate your assumption as a proper **hypothesis**, define an alternative $H_0$, and then perform a nice and clean hypothesis test.

Comment: Thanks. I used Kruskal–Wallis test. Just wanted to try cluster analysis as an experiment (and a learning experience).